# Proof of "If M and N are positive definite, then the products MNM and NMN are also positive definite"

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix#:%7E:text=Multiplication%5Bedit%5D-,If,are%20also%20positive%20definite,-.%20If) on Wikipedia, it states that:

"If M and N are positive definite, then the products MNM and NMN are also positive definite"

I've tried looking for a proof of this statement, but I cannot find one. I also tried proving it myself and I couldn't come up with it.

Can someone enlighten me to the proof of this statement? It has no citation or proof given.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $z^T MNM z=(Mz)^T N (Mz)> 0$. Here we use that $M$ is symmetric and $N$ is PD, $z\ne 0$, $Mz\ne 0$ (because $M$ is invertible).

Comment: I think you can simplify your steps by leaving $N$ alone. $z^\top M = z^\top M^\top = (Mz)^\top$.

Comment: I know, just made a change.

Comment: How do we know that $z$ is not equal to $0$ @markvs? Thanks for the help.

EDIT: nevermind I understand now. We know that N is already PD so the $(Mz)$ cant be equal to $0$.

Comment: We can even say a bit more: if $M$ is real symmetric positive definite and $P$ is real square full rank, then $P^TMP$ is positive definite. The matrices $M$ and $P^TMP$ are said to be congruent. Matrix congruence arises when considering the effect of change of basis on the Gram matrix attached to a bilinear form or quadratic form on a finite-dimensional vector space: two matrices are congruent if and only if they represent the same bilinear form with respect to different bases. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence